# Multiple camera images on Android-Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I'm very new to android development and need some help with a camera application I'm trying.

My screen consists of 4 image views and 4 buttons.
The image views are placed in the top left / top right / bottom left / bottom right corners of the screen.
The buttons are right under each of these image views.

I'd like the buttons to open the camera and capture images for the respective corners.
Is there a better way to program the camera function than to write button on click listener 4 different times?

I tried writing one single function to call camera intent.

```
private val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 0

fun onCapture(view: View) {
    val callCameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

And add the below for each of the buttons in the xml -

```
android:onClick="onCapture"
```

However, to view the captured image, the examples I've seen online all show the output image while overriding the onActivityResult function.
Something like this -

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when(requestCode) {
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap)
                }
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unrecognized request code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

This would help to fill one image per activity.
But not 4.

Can you let me know how I can better write to capture individual images for each of the corners after its respective button click.

Comment: Tag your buttons. button1.setTag(1); and so on. startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE + view.getTag())

Comment: You could also tag with the right imageview. button3.setTag(imageView3); And in onClick save it to a member of the activity: actualImageView = view.getTag(); and use the actualImageView in onActivityResult.